# Dictionaries sharing similar keys and how to use 2 dictionaries together

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary with the following:

```
{ 0: Apple, 1: Banana, 2: Orange}
```

and another dictionary with the following :

```
{0: 59.0, 1: 15.0, 2: 13.0}
```

Since both dictionaries use similar keys with `0,1,2`  I wanted to combine them to print out:

```
Apple, 59.0, Banana, 15.0, Orange, 13.0
```

Any ideas or help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: In which order? What happens if a key is in dict A but not in B? What about the other way around?

Comment: @MuslimbekAbduganiev I've tried making 2 helper functions for each dictionary to split it up and then the main function to call it together to produce the desired outcome but I'm lost on where or how to start the main function

Comment: @Selcuk For my question at least the order doesn't matter as both dictionaries have the same keys but that is a good point you've made.

Answer (score 1):

If you're absolutely sure that the two sets of dictionary keys coincide, you can do a dict comprehension on the items of the first dictionary and assign values from the second one:

```
dict1 = {0: "Apple", 1: "Banana", 2: "Orange"}
dict2 = {0: 59.0, 1: 15.0, 2: 13.0}

new_dict = {value: dict2[key] for key, value in dict1.items()}
```

If the keys don't exactly coincide between the dicts, you'll be missing out on items or get errors.

*Edit*: As pointed out in the comments, this creates a dictionary with the values of the first dict as the new keys. It seems that you wanted to have a list of the values, alternating between the two original dicts. As suggested by user Selcuk:

```
[i for key, value in dict1.items() for i in (value, dict2[key])]
```

Comment: This creates a new `dict`. I am not sure that's what OP wants from looking at their expected output: `Apple, 59.0, Banana, 15.0, Orange, 13.0`

Comment: Hm, you're right. Somehow my brain interpreted that expected output as a dict mapping.

Comment: You can still use the same method and just change your answer to a nested list comprehension: `[i for key, value in dict1.items() for i in (value, dict2[key])]`

Comment: Indeed. Although I have to admit, that list comprehension hurts my brain a little. I would have expected the result to be a nested list.

Comment: Fair enough, it's a bit confusing. A nested list comprehension will produce a flat list while a single list comprehension will produce a list of lists, similar to a single `for` loop vs nested loops.